# Generic that create's an object with string and trype

Tags: typescript, generics

How can I get `MinObj` to work as expected to create `{ 'name': string }`?

```
type MinObj<Key extends string, Type> = { [a: Key]: Type }

type x = MinObj<'name', string>
```

[Playground Link](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAsglgOwPICMBWAeA0hEUIAewECAJgM5TnABOiA5gDRQAq40hxZlAhgiAD4oAXigBvKAG0eALig4QAXTltIUAL4AobaDUERsRKkwByBDwC2EE82p0E9AUA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the mapped type `Record`, it does exactly what you want:

```
type x = Record<'name', string>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAHlC8UBKEDGB7ATgEwDwHIA7AQwFsJ8AaKAZ2EwEtCBzAPiA)